Is it common for Dell gamer laptops with Nvidia GPU's to not support Device Encryption?
I cannot get some new Dell G15 5530 (W11Pro 23H2) laptops, which have Nvidia RTX 4060 GPU's, to offer device encryption as an option in settings.
Dell support refuses to help much because I upgraded Windows 11 Home to Pro soon after being handed this project. But they were willing to state in a chat that "hardware based device encryption is not an option for this model." I can only guess that they say this because these laptops have the Nvidia GPU's. Thus this post.
One ray of hope is provided by this doc from Microsoft that says "Starting in Windows 11, version 24H2, the prerequisites of DMA and HSTI/Modern Standby are removed." Might upgrading to 24H2 enable these laptops to support "Device Encryption Support"?
If the reader wants further details:
MSINFO32 reports "Device Encryption Support" lists two "reasons for failed automatic device encryption":

PCR7 binding is not supported
Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected (NVDIA GPU?)

Other relevant data points from MSINFO32:
BIOS Mode = UEFI
Secure Boot State = ON
PCR7 Configuration = Binding Not Possible


Asking if something happens to other people isn't a particularly helpful question, and is not going to be well received on this site. Ask about solving YOUR problem, and that'll probably be something we can help with. I don't get your leap to blaming nVidia. None of the info you've posted actually points at the GPU, just your assumptions making that leap. Is there some other evidence that is pointing ACTUALLY at the GPU?

No, it has nothing to do with the GPU. It's about Home vs Pro. Dell supports the original OS only.

Device Encryption only applies to Windows 11 Home; if you have a professional, you would be using BitLocker. There are many reasons why the PCR7 configuration makes Binding Impossible. Keep in mind that BitLocker does not require TPM, although it's more secure if TPM is used. To diagnose this problem, I would need screenshots from various pages within Settings. Your issue has nothing to do with the GPU.

Furthermore,  "Might upgrading to 24H2 enable these laptops to support "Device Encryption Support"?" - Only if you were to perform a clean install, now I don't recommend that, since you'll probably just copy the configuration over to the new install and end up in the same situation. Try this

The most likely reason that PC7 is not available is that  Modern Standby is disabled.  I know my desktop has it disabled, and PC7 is not available, but I most certainly have BitLocker enabled. Post the output of powercfg /a

You can try to disable the UEFI CA 2011 certificate in your Secure Boot settings. This will allow BitLocker to bind to PCR 7 instead of PCR 0, 2, 4, 11. To disable the UEFI CA 2011 certificate in Secure Boot settings, you need to go to the UEFI menu and find the Secure Boot setting.

Can you detail the process? The author might be unaware of the process.  Why does this certificate cause this problem?  Details like this are important to provide in an answer like this.
